# Timeout when I execute query from php code

Tags: php, database, oracle, timeout

I'm using PHP with oracle 10 as database when I execute this query I get always a timeout problem, I've raise it to 1000s but it still the same problem.

I've checked oracle logs but I didn't find any information

```
DECLARE RET NUMBER; 
        CHR VARCHAR2(80);
BEGIN 
    DBMS_PIPE.PURGE('SPAq3qefqefhd1f19b21c3a7gvt30'); 
    DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE('q3qefqefhd1f19b21c3a7gvt30;100;14;3345 0047 10/02/2023 S X2009292 '); 
    RET := DBMS_PIPE.SEND_MESSAGE('SPA');
    IF RET = 0 THEN 
        RET := DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE('SPAq3qefqefhd1f19b21c3a7gvt30', '100'); 
        IF RET = 0 THEN 
            DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(CHR); 
            :ret_string := CHR; 
        ELSIF RET = 1 THEN 
            :ret_string := 'KOTIMEOUT'; 
        ELSE :ret_string := 'KOCOMMERROR'; 
        END IF; 
    ELSIF RET = 1 THEN 
        :ret_string := 'KOTIMEOUTSEND'; 
    ELSIF RET = 3 THEN 
        :ret_string := 'KOINTERRUPTSEND'; 
    ELSE 
        :ret_string := 'KOERRORSEND'; 
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: the problem is not about PHP, it's about the query

Comment: What error do you get, and what have you raised "to 1000s"? You haven't shown a query; you're sending and receiving messages. Is it timing out sending a message, or receiving on? (You can add debugs after each step if you don't know.) Is there some other process listening for and responding to your messages, is that actually running, and what does that see happening - does it never get it, or spends a long time processing before responding?

Comment: Use any database client to run the query and check how long it takes to return the results. That way you can see if it's related to your code or your query. PHP has a default timeout of 30 seconds, you can call `set_time_limit(300);` before running the query in PHP to extend the timeout (to 5 minutes). However, extending the timeout is not the solution, probably query optimization, database structure optimization (like creating indexes, or the db server is too slow).

Comment: @Gonzalingui, the problem is not linked to php configuration, the same problem when I run the query with sqldeveloper

Comment: @AlexPoole how can I check if there is  some other process listening for and responding to the messages

Comment: when I run SELECT count(*) FROM V$SESSION; I get 14
can I close them ?
now only me use the application

Comment: Well, what are you expecting to process the messages you are sending? Are you communicating with something you've also written, or a third-party application?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes my app communicate with two others apps

Comment: Are they running? If so do they show your message being received? Or a delay or error generating a response? You still haven't said exactly what error you get or which statement in your code gets it - send, receive, something else..

Comment: I said there is no error message,
only timeout

Comment: Surely a timeout is an error? OK... so does "I get always a timeout problem" actually mean "ret_string is set to 'KOTIMEOUT'"? And "I've raise it to 1000s" means you changed the second argument `'100'` (which should just be `100`, without quotes) to a much higher number? If so then application(s) you are communicating with *are not sending a response* in that timeout window, or probably at all. You need to investigate what it happening at *their* end - again, whether they receive your message, or fail processing it, or fail responding, or are not running at all.